# Loop over lines character by character

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix

I am trying to treat a series of letters as an array in order to loop through each letter in a for loop, line by line, element by element.

My `$data` after extracting a column looks something like:

```
ACACACACACA
CGCGCGCGGGG
TATATATAAAA
GAGAAAGAAGG
TGGTTTTGGTG
```

My script:

```
for j in `cat $data` # go line by line
do
    for k in "${j[@]}" # go through each letter element by element
    do
        echo $k
    done
done
```

Gives the output:

```
ACACACACACA
CGCGCGCGGGG
TATATATAAAA
...
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
A
C
A
C
A
C
...
G
T
G
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or is there a better way to call each element of the line?

Comment: Not sure on the `for` loop here, but you could just do `cat $data | sed 's/./&\n/g'` to get this output. Or with `awk`: `cat $data | awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: It should definitely be 'echo' and not 'cat'.  Otherwise, that command is going to try to cat a file named whatever is in your data which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: `tr -d '\n' < "$data" | sed 's/./&\n/g'`

Comment: `echo ACACACACACA | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'` might give you a clue. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pure bash, but this gets you what you're after:

```
for j in `echo $data | grep -o .`
do
  echo $j
done
```

The grep command matches every single character and prints it out (or in this case, stores it in the variable j where I assume you intend to do more than just echo it).

Comment: For my edification, could you explain why `echo $data | grep -o .` works but not `echo $data | grep -o` (no period)?

Comment: @anita That\`s because `grep` needs a pattern to match against. When you omit the `.` (match any character), you leave `grep` unsure what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's always uppercase letters:

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z]/&\n/g' inputFile
```

or use the following to replace any character and number with the same character or number followed by a newline.

```
$ sed 's/./&\n/g' inputFile
```

OR if you have `fold` available,

```
$ fold -w1 inputFile
```

`fold` wraps line. With `-w1` option, it wraps to a fix width of `1`.

Comment: `echo "ACGT" | sed 's/[A-Z]/&\n/g'` gives me `AnCnGnTn` and `echo "ACGT" | sed 's/./&\n/g'` gives me `AnCnGnTn` as well. Doesn't seem to work for me?

Answer (score 1):

The shortest option:

```
fold -1 <<<"$data"
```